# India - ID proof for child traveling on domestic flight

Tags: air-travel, india, children, domestic-travel, identity-cards

My 8 yr old child is not carrying his Aadhar card with him. Can he travel on domestic flight without ID proof? Can E-aadhar be used as Proof of identity to travel within India?

He has to travel from Jaipur to Mumbai. He will be accompanied by his grand parents who have valid documents.

Comment: Can you make the question more self-contained and thus more interesting? Could say what aadhar and E aadhar is?

Comment: @guest Modified the question to make it clear. Aadhar is the national ID card of India. E-aadhar is the electronic copy.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can show E-aadhar or picture of your kid stored in his grandparent's  phone.

Comment: Do you have a link to and a quote from an official website stating this is enough? As it stands this answer is just a 'believe me' and why would we believe you. If not edited, this answer may be deleted.